# Saving/Reloading user entry (textbox values, names) in C# WPF - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I would like to ask if you could direct me towards a solution to my problem. What I would like to do is that the user would input name of patient and some values in the textboxes (weight, protein, etc) and these would be stored somewhere. The name/patient would be reloaded with the values and you could edit them and save again. There would be a list of patients (from drop-down menu for example). I wanted to post a screenshot of my app, but I need more reputation.

How can I achieve this in a simple way? Is it what databases are for or is there something similar? I tried SQLite, but it's not working with VS 2017. What about other embedded databases or serialization?
If databases are solution, I am fine with server-less ones.

Thank you very much![enter image description here]

Comment: Sure, you can use a database. What is your *specific question*?

Comment: To get SQLite working with EF in VS2017 you need to add an extension, all I know is it's called `extension.vsix` can't find it again, sorry

Comment: Got it from here https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Release-notes

Comment: Hi gyus, if you will give me enough reputation points, I would like to post the image of my app here - it will be much clearer! Peter K

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library to store the values in an SQLite database. It has a good tutorial in the README.

Comment: Yes, SQLite in the end was the answer. I tried XML and also JSON that are both great (JSON better).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a part of my question. 
I used XML method where I take whatever is in the textboxes and store it in XML file that is named aftere that particular person. Code:

```
public class SaveXML
    {
        public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

public class Information
    {
        private string txtdata1;
        private string txtdata2;
        private string txtdata3;

        public string PatientName
        {
            get { return txtdata1; }
            set { txtdata1 = value; }
        }

        public string PatientWeight
        {
            get { return txtdata2; }
            set { txtdata2 = value; }
        }

        public string PatientTFIWeight
        {
            get { return txtdata3; }
            set { txtdata3 = value; }
        }
    }

private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Information info = new Information();
                info.PatientName = Patient.Text;
                info.PatientWeight = Weight.Text;
                info.PatientTFIWeight = TFIWeight.Text;
                SaveXML.SaveData(info, Patient.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```